# The tables cannot be seen

Tags: datatables, powerbi

In power bi on the left side there are usually 3 buttons: the dashboard, the tables, and the links between the tables.
For some reason I don't see the tables button, why is it like that?

I don't know why it doesn't work, it's tables that I loaded just now and they are updated in safe SQL
In addition, when I look at the connections between the tables I see the tables there.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't show us any code.

Answer (score 0):

when you import data by direct query way you cannot see the tables in left side.